# Read from Blynk terminal number to arduino

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, blynk, terminal

I have a problem in sending numbers from blynk terminal to arduino serial monitor. When I send any number from blynk terminal the arduino always getting 1. How can I get any number please help me. Thank you.

Here's my code

```
BLYNK_WRITE(V0){
  int pinValue = param.asInt(); // Int Value
  String i = param.asStr(); //String Value
  Serial.println(pinValue);
 
 if(i == "A"){
      Serial.println("Ready to enroll a fingerprint!");
      Serial.println("Please type in the ID # (from 1 to 127) you want to delete...");
      
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V0, "Ready to enroll a fingerprint!");
      Blynk.virtualWrite(V0, "Please type in the ID # (from 1 to 127) you want to save this finger 
      as..."); 

      uint8_t num = 0;
        
        while (num == 0) {
          while (! Serial.available());
          num = Serial.parseInt();
        }
      Serial.print("Enrolling ID #");
      Serial.print(num);
 }
}
```

The value output of num is always 1 even I sent a different number.

Comment: the number is sent as string. so use param.asStr(), then convert it to number

Comment: I already know that, but the actual problem was any value that was sent to arduino serial monitor becomes 1

Comment: how do you know?. you don't print it. you print the int value

Comment: I tried it earlier, the value always get 1. please help