# Arduino wait for incomming data from blynk terminal

Tags: arduino-mega, serial-data, blynk, terminal

I need to add wait command in code where it waits the next input value from blynk terminal to arduino? How can I do that? please help, I will appreciate your help, Thank you.

Here is my code

```
BLYNK_WRITE(V0)
{
 

     String i = param.asStr(); //String Value from blynk
    
      if(i == "A"){
          Serial.println("Ready to enroll a fingerprint!");
          Serial.println("Please type in the ID # (from 1 to 127) you want to save this finger as...");

          Blynk.virtualWrite(V0, "Ready to enroll a fingerprint!");
          Blynk.virtualWrite(V0, "Please type in the ID # (from 1 to 127) you want to save this finger");

int numb = i.parseInt; //I need to add a command here to wait for the next blynk terminal value

  Serial.print("Enrolling ID #");
  Serial.print(numb);
}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read from Blynk terminal number to arduino](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/78203/read-from-blynk-terminal-number-to-arduino)

Comment: No, It was a different problem

Comment: you can't wait in blynk handler function. let it end. it will be called with the next input. use some variable to remember in which step of user input the code is